# cppunit: setUp() and tearDown()

Tags: c++, unit-testing, methods, attributes, cppunit

I use the framework cppunit to test my classes,I want to know if the methods `TestFixture::setUp()` and `TestFixture::tearDown()` are called one time for TEST_SUITE or they are called for each method added to this suite

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The methods wrap each individual test case.  From the [docs](http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/1.8.0/class_cpp_unit_1_1_test_fixture.html#_details):

> Each test runs in its own fixture so there can be no side effects
>   among test runs.

Comment: thank u for your time, so for example if I have  an attribute `Field` initialized in the  `setUp()`, it will be destroyed in the `tearDown()` after the first case and reinitialized for the next case, is that what you mean?